# Should I initialize variables in JavaScript with default values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, variable-declaration, variable-initialization

I have an AngularJS controller. I follow [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#bindable-members-up-top) guide in binding variables on the top. My question is: is there any performance gain in initializing variables with default values while declaring them, or it impacts on performance adversely?

```
function someCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.someVar = '';    // Should it rather be vm.someVar; ?
}
```

I have asked this in AngularJS context. However, this is a general JavaScript question.

**UPDATE:** What about the following scenario?

```
function someCtrl($scope) {
    var someVar = '';    // Should it rather be var someVar; ?
}
```

Comment: you don't need to initialise it at all, unless it's an array (to push some values in it later), a nested object (to write down properties), or some hardcoded value

Answer (score 1):

> `vm.someVar = '';` - Should it rather be `vm.someVar;`?

That's neither a variable nor a declaration.

It's an assignment that creates a property on the `vm` object. In contrast, `vm.someVar;` is just a no-op (it does nothing) and should be dropped altogether.

Yes, if you want to create properties you *need* to initialise them. You could initialise them with `undefined`, but it's better to initialise them with a default value of the same type they would later have. And yes, it is a good practice to create properties in the constructor (when creating the object) instead of adding them after the fact.

Comment: 1. Can you answer the same question, but with `var someVar` instead of `vm.someVar` context?

2. Other than being a good practice, is there any performance loss or gain (Even the slightest)?

Comment: @AhsenKh `this` in controller is used as scope along with _controllerAs_ syntax (basically same as `$scope.someVar`). The variable bounded to scope can be displayed in HTML as `{{someVar}}`. Using `var someVar` is fine too, but it will not be attached to scope and so you can't show it in HTML

Comment: @AhsenKh 1) I declare variables where I use them, so I always initialise them anyway. Doesn't really matter though. 2) Yes, creating objects with all the properties they will need and not changing their shape later is better for performance.